# How to fix class not found error for namespaced Enums?

Tags: php, laravel

I have an `enums` folder created manually in the root directory of a Laravel project. Currently, there is only one file called `TransactionTypes` and I want to use it in my migration (in another file too in the future). However, when I test the app, it throws an error.

```sh
Class "Enums\TransactionTypes" not found
```

My migration that uses this enum look like this

```php
<?php

use App\Models\Foodstuff;
use Enums\TransactionTypes;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('transactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->foreignIdFor(Foodstuff::class);
            $table->enum('type', TransactionTypes::cases()); // HERE
            $table->unsignedInteger('stock');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('transactions');
    }
};
```

I have already declared a `namespace` in my enum

```php
<?php

namespace Enums;

enum TransactionTypes
{
    case in;
    case out;
    case cancelled;
    case returned;
}
```

I tried to execute `sail composer dump-autoload` but it still doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you certain that the autoloader settings in your composer.json match where in the filesystem that enum definition exists?

Comment: I didn't set anything inside composer.json but for now, following Guille's solution works for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good practice to have enums folder inside app folder maybe change it to

`app/Enums/TransactionTypes.php`

Second, i recommend some changes in the enum class:

- Change namespace to `App\Enums`
- Add return type
- Add values to cases

```
<?php

namespace App\Enums;

enum TransactionTypes: string
{
    case in = "in";
    case out = "out";
    case cancelled = "cancelled";
    case returned = "returned";
}
```

Third, run `sail composer dump-autoload`